# Userform runtime error 380- could not set the rowsource property - fix?

Tags: vba, runtime-error, userform

Code has been working perfectly for past year. Made some edits and extended some of the data - ensured it was all lined up correct at the time. I came to use it but now I am getting the following error

> runtime error 380: could not set the rowsource property"

I have narrowed it down to `.RowSource = "VOLNAME2"` but I haven't changed anything about this data.

The error initially comes up when you press the button to bring this UserForm up, so debug starts on `newlog.show` (separate module). However, I used F8 to highlight the error line as above.

I tried redefining the name manager and renaming it. Deleted and re-entered it. I had a look at some other answers but couldn't see anything that stood out as the answer.

```
Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim R As Range
Me.TextBox2.Locked = True
Me.TextBox3.Locked = True
Me.CommandButton1.Enabled = False      
With Me.ComboBox4
  .RowSource = "VOLNAME2"
  .MatchEntry = fmMatchEntryComplete
  .Style = fmStyleDropDownList
End With 

With Me.ComboBox1
  .RowSource = ""
  .MatchEntry = fmMatchEntryComplete
  .Style = fmStyleDropDownList
  For Each R In Range("'Database'!F4:F23")
    .AddItem R.Text
  Next
End With

With Me.ComboBox3
 .RowSource = ""
 .MatchEntry = fmMatchEntryComplete
 .Style = fmStyleDropDownList
 For Each R In Range("'Database'!F26:F51")
   .AddItem R.Text
  Next
End With

With Me.ComboBox2
 .RowSource = ""
 .MatchEntry = fmMatchEntryComplete
 .Style = fmStyleDropDownList
 For Each R In Range("'Database'!H3:H32")
   .AddItem R.Text
  Next
End With
End Sub
```

I am expecting the defined name "volname2" to populate combobox 4

Comment: Whats the RowSourceType for Combo4?  Make sure its set to Value List.

Comment: sorry mike - where do i find this? I can't see it in the properties section.

Comment: Is this in Excel or Access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't update the rowSource for these to straight values, they require a range or some other lookup.
Change:

```
With Me.ComboBox4
  .RowSource = "VOLNAME2"
  .MatchEntry = fmMatchEntryComplete
  .Style = fmStyleDropDownList
End With
```

To one of these options:

Option - 1  Clears the list adds the requested text and sets the index to display that value

```
ComboBox1.Clear 
ComboBox1.AddItem ("volname2")
ComboBox1.ListIndex = 0
```

Option 2 - Clears the list and sets the text value to requested value.  Personally this is a bad choice, because you'll have to forcibly clear the text value with .Text = "" if you want to re-use it.

```
ComboBox1.Clear 
ComboBox1.Text = "volname2"
```

Comment: Hi Mike, Thanks for you help. I followed option 1 but has just written the word volname2 in the listbox rather than the list itself.

Comment: Odd, it puts it in the list for me.  ComboBox1.ListIndex = 0 is just setting it automatically select the first option in the list as the set value when it opens.  If you want them to select it, remove the ListIndex = 0

Comment: Fixed! I took out the =0 line and changed it from .additem to .rowsource and used the cell references instead of the defined range. Thanks for all your help Mike.